# JS and CSS in hook_preprocess_hook()

Tags: theming

In the project I am working on I have created a theme hook that renders a .tpl.php file:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function my_module_theme() {

  $theme['my_module_list'] = array(
    'variables' => array(
      '#markup' => array(),
    ),
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module'),
    'template' => 'templates/my_module_list',
  );

  return $theme;
}
```

Then I want some JS and CSS to be added only when this theme hook is used in the current page. Thus I implemented of theme_preprocess_hook() as such:

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess(). 
 */
function my_theme_preprocess_my_module_list(&$vars) {
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module') . '/js/my_module.js');
  drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module') . '/css/my_module.css');
}
```

However it appears that the preprocess function is not called every time the hook is used resulting in CSS and JS not being added. What am I missing? Is it bad practice to add it there? And if yes where should I add it in order for it to be loaded only when necessary? I couldn't find any documentation that clarifies it and I've also seen it done other places.

Thanks a lot in advance :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would add JS/CSS files inside the preprocess_page() function. If I don't want the CSS/JS files loading on some pages I will use an IF statement and check for a setting or if something exists etc, this will depend on the project.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use info files to add JS and CSS? My experience says it is the best way - it's stable, clean, easy to fint and tune. Also, it helps with aggregation and caching if you always have one set on all pages.

For conditionals - just use CSS and JS rules to find out if the page is one they need to be applied on. For example, test for specific class on `<body>` element, or script / style elements by their specific class or id.

Comment: I totally agree: Adding the same JavaScript and CSS files to all the pages makes possible to Drupal to aggregate and cache them.